# SKlearn RandomForestClassifier ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn

I am passing a data frame with each row contains two columns that contains numpy arrays two randomforestclassifier

i.e.
[image]

it gives me this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-110-e0a56908e930> in <module>()
      1 clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2)
----> 2 clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

sklearn\ensemble\forest.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    245         """
    246         # Validate or convert input data
--> 247         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse="csc", dtype=DTYPE)
    248         y = check_array(y, accept_sparse='csc', ensure_2d=False, dtype=None)
    249         if sample_weight is not None:

sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    431                                       force_all_finite)
    432     else:
--> 433         array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
    434 
    435         if ensure_2d:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I have went through two nearly same issues here on stack overflow with no useful answers, that's why I created a new question

Comment: Classifier expects to receive rows with numerical values, it does not know what to do with nested arrays.

Comment: What does this data represent

Comment: @VivekKumar would it really make a difference ?

Comment: Depending on what the data represents, the above data can be converted into a 2-d array appropriate for scikit estimators. Also please check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I already tried that and it gives the same error.

Comment: What did you do? Please show the code and first explain more about the problem and the data. We are here to help, but cant if you dont explain.

Comment: The arrays are histograms of Images so I did represented the histogram in 2d format instead of 1d array and it didn't work, what I did is that I applied np function of converting a 1d array to 2d array just as simple as that and also represented the pixels instead of histogram but as 2d matrix of the image and it doesn't work because the rest of the data in the same row are all numeric, I researched a bit if random forest classifier can take in mixed values as input or only numeric and it seems as @hellpanderr stated that classifier expect to get only numeric values, but kindly guide me.